# python telethon как писать в чате от имени канала

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Можно ли через telethon писать в чат от имени канала? В документации инфы об этом не нашёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала проверьте, что вы можете отправить сообщение другому каналу или пользователю. если вы не можете, вы должны поделиться всем кодом.

затем убедитесь, что учетная запись, которую вы используете в этом случае, является администратором канала. невозможно получить эту ошибку, если учетная запись является администратором. также проверьте права администратора и убедитесь, что сообщение сообщения включено.

```
await client.send_message(entity='my channel name', message=message)
```

Comment: А, оказывается если канал добавить в чат, то он будет автоматом пересылать туда всё, что есть у него. Чет не заметил этого.